# How to add the transform matrix attribute to svg text?

Tags: php, svg

I have svg code which i need to add matrix property in svg g tag transform. I have added the matrix code property from the given svg value. Actualy i am recreating svg element myself using php from the generated svg values. or is there a way to calculate to svg transform matrix property.

How i calculated matrix is (itemzoom_first_value+1) and (itemzoom_second_value+1).

```
<svg>
      <g id="0.601788739906624" transform="matrix(1.6636363636364 0 0 1.7414965986395 -6 372.3537414966)">
    <text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="0" y="0" text-anchor="left" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1" itemzoom="0.6636363636363637 0.7414965986394558">Hello
    </text>
    </g>
<svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SVG does not have the itemzoom property
- The name of the unique identifier must not begin with a digit. Assign
  a name that starts with a letter, for example, id = "txt1"
- The origin svg is the upper-left corner. To see the text you need the
  "y" coordinate for the text to assign a positive value, greater than
  the font size.
- To increase the text size, you can use the `scale (2)` command to
  increase the size twice, or any other values, for example:

  `scale (1.2 1.5)` to increase the "X" axis by 1.2 times and 1.5 by axis "Y"

Below is your svg code with corrections

```html
<svg >
      <g id="txt1" >
    <text y="60" fill="#000000" stroke="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" text-anchor="left" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine"  >Hello  </text>
    </g>
<svg>
```

Example of animating text resizing when hovering over

```html
<svg >
      <g id="txt1" >
    <text y="30" fill="#000000" stroke="none"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" text-anchor="left" font-size="32" font-family="Twine"  >Hello  </text>
    </g>  
 <animateTransform xlink:href="#txt1"  attributeName="transform" type="scale" dur="4s"  begin="txt1.mouseover" end="txt1.mouseout"  values="1;4;1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
<svg>
```

Comment: Isn't the OP looking for a way to read in an XML file using php, change it and then write out that modified XML file?

Comment: @RobertLongson  You're right. This is the solution that the author of the question is looking for. I gave another option for positioning and modifying the size of the text. Maybe it will be useful to someone.